# Can a Flask program be run/debugged in Spyder?

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, spyder

I am trying a simple Flask tutorial I found on-line.  Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

# configuration
DEBUG = True

# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# enable CORS
CORS(app)

# sanity check route
@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping_pong():
    return jsonify('pong!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In `Spyder` if I run the File, it works fine.  However, I would like to be able to debug and execute statements as I select them.  When I select the entire contents and execute (via the interactive console), I get the error below.  Is there a way to make this work?

```
Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 Debug mode: on
 Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 Restarting with stat
/opt/local/anaconda3/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

Comment: Update: none of the answers provided up until work.  I switched to "PyCharm" run within there and debugging just works exactly as expected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably try this code below scenario

```
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication

def create_app():
    # Insert whatever else you do in your Flask app factory.

    if app.debug:
        app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, evalex=True)

    return app
```

This will enable debugging your application

For complete source code with examples please check below [link](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `app.run()` use`app.run(debug = False)`, for the purpose of running.